# Proc sql and macro variables

Tags: sas

I am trying to run a code that should work on tables created considering different factors. As these factors can be more than 1, I decided to create a macro `%let` to list them:

```
%let list= factor1 factor2 ...;
```

What I would like to do is run a code to create these tables using different factors. For each factor,  I computed using `proc means` the mean and the standard deviation, so I should have the variables `&list._mean` and `&list._stddev` in the table created by the `proc means` for each factor. This table is labelled as `t2` and I need to join to another table, `t1`. From t1 I am considering all the variables.

My main difficulties are, therefore, in the proc sql:

```
proc sql;
create table new_table as
select t1.*
, t2.&list._mean as mean
, t2.&list._stddev as stddev
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2
on t1.time=t2.time
order by t2.&list.
quit;
```

This code is returning an error and I think because I am considering `t2.factor1 factor2`, i.e. `t2` is only applied to the first factor, not to the second one. 
What I would expect is the following:

```
  proc sql;
    create table new_table as
    select t1.*
    , t2.factor1._mean as mean
    , t2.factor1._stddev as stddev
    from table1 as t1
    left join table2 as t2
    on t1.time=t2.time
    order by t2.factor1.
    quit;
```

and another one for factor2. 
UPDATE CODE:

```
%macro test_v1(
     _dtb
    ,_input
    ,_output
    ,_time
    ,_factor
);

data &_input.;
    set &_dtb..&_input.;
    keep &_col_period. &_factor.;
run;

proc sort data = work.&_input.
           out = &_input._1;
    by &_factor. &_time.;
run;

%put ERROR: 2

proc means data=&_input._1 nonobs mean stddev;
    class &_time.;
    var &_factor.;
    output out=&_input._n (drop=_TYPE_) mean= stddev= /autoname ;
run;

%put ERROR: 3

proc sql;
create table work.&_input._data as 
select t1.*
        ,t2.&_factor._mean as mean
        ,t2.&_factor._stddev as stddev
from &_input. as t1
left join &_input._n as t2
on t1.&_time.=t2.&_time.
order by &_factor.;
quit;

%mend test_v1;
```

Then my question is on how I can consider multiple factors, defined into a macro as a list, as columns of tables and as input data into a macro (for example: `%test(dataset, tablename, list)`.

Comment: Even if you fix your syntax error your plan cannot work.  You cannot rename both FACTOR1_MEAN and FACTOR2_MEAN to the same name.

Comment: i think you can use one step (proc sort) instead of two steps(data+proc sort):`proc sort data = have1(keep=time factor1)
           out = have3_1;
    by factor1 time;
run;` instead of `data data have2;
    set have1;
    keep time factor1;
run;

proc sort data = have2
           out = have2_1;
    by factor1 time;
run;`

Comment: Why does your macro reference a totally undefined macro variable, `_col_period`? Why do you sort by the "factor" variables instead TIME? Are you using the FACTOR variables as analysis variables or grouping variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add macro loop to your macros by scanning list of factors. It could look like:

```
%macro test(list);
   %do i=1 to %sysfunc(countw(&list,%str( )));
      %let factorname=%scan(&list,&i,%str( ));
       /* if macro variable list equals factor1 factor2 then there would be
       two iterations in loop, i=1 factorname=factor1 and i=2 factorname=2*/
      /*your code here*/
   %end
%mend test;
```

UPDATE:

```
%macro test(_input, _output, factors_list); %macro d; %mend d;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&factors_list,%str( )));
%let tfactor=%scan(&factors_list,&i,%str( ));
proc sort data = work.&_input.
           out = &_input._1;
    by &factors_list. time;
run;

proc means data=&_input._1 nonobs mean stddev;
    class time;
    var &tfactor.;
    output out=&_input._num (drop=_TYPE_) mean= stddev= /autoname ;
run;

proc sql;
   create table &_output._&tfactor as
   select t1.*
   , t2.&tfactor._mean as mean
   , t2.&tfactor._stddev as stddev
   from &_input as t1
   left join &_input._num as t2
   on t1.time=t2.time
   order by t1.&tfactor;
quit;

%end;
%mend test;

%test(have,newdata,factor1 factor2);
```

Have dataset:

```
+------+---------+---------+
| time | factor1 | factor2 |
+------+---------+---------+
|    1 |   12345 |    1234 |
|    2 |     123 |      12 |
|    3 |       1 |      -1 |
|    4 |     -12 |    -123 |
|    5 |   -1234 |  -12345 |
|    6 |    9876 |     987 |
|    7 |      98 |       8 |
|    8 |       9 |       7 |
|    1 |    1234 |     123 |
|    2 |      12 |       1 |
|    3 |      12 |     -12 |
|    4 |    -123 |   -1234 |
|    5 |  -12345 | -123456 |
|    6 |     987 |      98 |
|    7 |       9 |      -9 |
|    8 |    1234 |    1234 |
+------+---------+---------+
```

NEWDATA_FACTOR1:

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
| time | factor1 | factor2 |  mean   |    stddev    |
+------+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
|    5 |  -12345 | -123456 | -6789.5 | 7856.6634458 |
|    5 |   -1234 |  -12345 | -6789.5 | 7856.6634458 |
|    4 |    -123 |   -1234 |   -67.5 | 78.488852712 |
|    4 |     -12 |    -123 |   -67.5 | 78.488852712 |
|    3 |       1 |      -1 |     6.5 | 7.7781745931 |
|    7 |       9 |      -9 |    53.5 | 62.932503526 |
|    8 |       9 |       7 |   621.5 | 866.20580695 |
|    3 |      12 |     -12 |     6.5 | 7.7781745931 |
|    2 |      12 |       1 |    67.5 | 78.488852712 |
|    7 |      98 |       8 |    53.5 | 62.932503526 |
|    2 |     123 |      12 |    67.5 | 78.488852712 |
|    6 |     987 |      98 |  5431.5 |  6285.472178 |
|    1 |    1234 |     123 |  6789.5 | 7856.6634458 |
|    8 |    1234 |    1234 |   621.5 | 866.20580695 |
|    6 |    9876 |     987 |  5431.5 |  6285.472178 |
|    1 |   12345 |    1234 |  6789.5 | 7856.6634458 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

NEWDATA_FACTOR2:

```
+------+---------+---------+----------+--------------+
| time | factor1 | factor2 |   mean   |    stddev    |
+------+---------+---------+----------+--------------+
|    5 |  -12345 | -123456 | -67900.5 | 78567.341564 |
|    5 |   -1234 |  -12345 | -67900.5 | 78567.341564 |
|    4 |    -123 |   -1234 |   -678.5 |  785.5956339 |
|    4 |     -12 |    -123 |   -678.5 |  785.5956339 |
|    3 |      12 |     -12 |     -6.5 | 7.7781745931 |
|    7 |       9 |      -9 |     -0.5 |  12.02081528 |
|    3 |       1 |      -1 |     -6.5 | 7.7781745931 |
|    2 |      12 |       1 |      6.5 | 7.7781745931 |
|    8 |       9 |       7 |    620.5 | 867.62002052 |
|    7 |      98 |       8 |     -0.5 |  12.02081528 |
|    2 |     123 |      12 |      6.5 | 7.7781745931 |
|    6 |     987 |      98 |    542.5 | 628.61792847 |
|    1 |    1234 |     123 |    678.5 |  785.5956339 |
|    6 |    9876 |     987 |    542.5 | 628.61792847 |
|    1 |   12345 |    1234 |    678.5 |  785.5956339 |
|    8 |    1234 |    1234 |    620.5 | 867.62002052 |
+------+---------+---------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey. %let list=factor1 factor2; I wrote in this way:

`%macro test(list);
    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list,%str()));
      %let factorname=%scan(&list,&i,%str());
      %macro_v1(dataset,table, time, &list);
    %end
%mend test;` but no output has been returned. Is it right how I have used list also in the macro_v1?

Comment: try this:`%macro test(list); %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list,%str())); %let factorname=%scan(&list,&i,%str()); %macro_v1(dataset,table, time, &factorname); %end; %mend test;  %test(&list);`

Comment: it has given me the following error: "ERROR: The text expression &list contains a recursive reference to the macro variable list.  The macro variable 
       will be assigned the null value."

Comment: @a.rimbaud try this:`%macro test(tlist); %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&tlist,%str())); %let factorname=%scan(&tlist,&i,%str()); %macro_v1(dataset,table, time, &factorname); %end; %mend test; %test(&list);`

Comment: Same error in the proc sql: t2.factor1_mean factor2_mean
3                                                          The SAS System                         09:01 Wednesday, November 27, 2019

                              ____________________
                              22
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, AS, 
              CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, FROM, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.  

22: LINE and COLUMN cannot be determined.

Comment: ok, try to rename inside the macros every call of macro variable "list" to , for example, "factor", like: from `t2.&list._mean as mean
, t2.&list._stddev as stddev` to `t2.&factor._mean as mean
, t2.&factor._stddev as stddev`. and in %macro statement rename : `%macro macro_v1(/*input params...*/,factor/*instead of list*/);` **OR** Rename macro variable list when you init it in let statement.`%let factors=factor1 factor2` instead of `%let list=factor1 factor2` and then in my code use `%test(&factors)`

Comment: I tried to do both solutions  you suggested (pratically the same), but I got the error when I try to use in the proc sql the variables created in the proc means. So I think something is not working in that part of code. With the loop I should be able to run one time for the first factor, creating the variable factor1_mean in the proc means, then considering this as new column. I do not know if this is the right way to create a new column that is a computed column from the proc mean..

Comment: @a.rimbaud add to your question whole macro code and if it possible data sample:)

Comment: I added the code. this is the macro that I would like to run inside the loop. factor is the list = factor1 factor2

Comment: Thank you so much Alexey for your help. May I ask you the reason why you used different tfactor and factor_list?

Comment: @a.rimbaud tfactor stores one factor from factor_list and in each iterations it changes. For example we have factor_list equals factor1 factor2 factor3, countw function counts num of word which split by space, then loop iterates by each word and tfactor contains the word in each iteration(on the first iteration tfactor contains first word of factor_list, which equals factor1, etc.)

Comment: Thank you Alexey

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that trying to use PROC SQL is what is making the problem hard. If you stick to just using normal SAS syntax your space delimited list of variable names is easy to use.

So taking your code and tweaking it a little:

```
%macro test_v1
(_dtb    /* Input libref */
,_input  /* Input member name */
,_output /* Output dataset */
,_time   /* Class/By variable(s) */
,_factor /* Analysis variable(s) */
);

proc sort data= &_dtb..&_input. out=_temp1;
  by &_time. ;
run;

proc means data=_temp1 nonobs mean stddev;
  by &_time.;
  var &_factor.;
  output out=_temp2 (drop=_TYPE_) mean= stddev= /autoname ;
run;

data &_output. ;
  merge _temp1 _temp2 ;
  by &_time.;
run;

%mend test_v1;
```

We can then test it using SASHELP.CLASS by using SEX as the "time" variable and HEIGHT and WEIGHT as the analysis variables.

```
%test_v1(_dtb=sashelp,_input=class,_output=want,_time=sex,_factor=height weight);
```

[image]

Comment: ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, AS, 
              CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, FROM, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.  
This is the error the I get. The issue with proc sql is that I am applying in this way t2. only to the first factor, factor1, so I have t2.factor1 factor2 and this is wrong, as I should have: t2.factor1, t2.factor2

Comment: @a.rimbaud As Tom shows `Proc MEANS` has a large feature set for you to use.  Instead of coding a macro that simply replaces args into statements learning the Procs statements and coding without a macro means there is less to support long-term and makes life easier for the coder or code inheritor.